# Connect as user with no password set on Postgresql 8.4 via JDBC

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a `PostgreSQL` 8.4 DB in Ubuntu 10.10 via the JDBC drivers. I'm connecting via `jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5433/dbname` because PostgreSQL is running on a non-default port 5433 so I have to specify the port.

I've already edited my `postgresql.conf` to set `listen_addresses = "*"`. I understand that even though it's localhost, it's still using TCP/IP to connect via JDBC.

My problem is that I created a user without a password. If i do not specify a password with `DriverManager.connect(url)`, it errors indicating that I need to specify a password for authentication. Every password I try, including empty string, fails to authenticate with the DB.

How can I connect?

Edit:
If connecting over wrong port, the error is : PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. When attempting to connect on the correct port, I'm getting PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user". THis is remedied by the accepted answer below.

Comment: Show the full, exact error message and stack trace. Your title says "connection refused", but your text says "it errors that I need to specify a password for authentication". These are completely different things; in the latter case a successful TCP/IP connection is made then authentication is refused. From the description it looks like you get the connection refused when you connect to the default port 5432, because Pg is running on port 5433, but your actual *problem* is nothing to do with the connection refused error and everything to do with auth. Also: PostgreSQL **8.8**? 8.4?

Comment: [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you can find versions of PostgreSQL that actually exist, "8.8" is not among them.

Comment: Craig, my apologies, I am on posgres 8.4. As for my errors, yes, I was receiving different errors depending on the port. It seems I am indeed on 5433. When i tried a different port, I was getting a connection refused, which is more a networking problem (wrong port) as you imply. I know that in SQLServer sometimes, the error is pretty generic and an authentication error doesn't necessarily mean that the specified DB exists, or may infact be a permissions issue.

Comment: @StealthRabbi You'll be glad to know that PgJDBC doesn't generally have that issue then :-) . Errors are generally pretty specific, especially connection/auth issues, and include the error message from the backend if there was one.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Can you *please* edit to add the actual error you get from PgJDBC, so others with the same problem can find this later?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have `pg_hba.conf` set to require `md5` authentication and the user has no password, then no authentication can occur.

```
ALTER USER the_user_name PASSWORD 'give_it_a_password';
```

Alternately, use `ident` or (for localhost only, unsafe) `trust` authentication for that user/db combo in `pg_hba.conf` if you really must have no password. This is usually a bad idea, it's much better to just set a password.

Demo:

```
$ psql -q -U postgres postgres
postgres=# CREATE USER nopw;
CREATE ROLE

$ psql -h localhost -U nopw postgres
Password for user nopw:               [pressed enter]
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

$ psql -q -U postgres postgres
postgres=# ALTER USER nopw PASSWORD 'test';
postgres=# \q

$ psql -q -h localhost -U nopw postgres
Password for user nopw:            [entered 'test' then pressed enter]
postgres=>
```

Comment: on my local dev machine, I was able to set it to trust mode as you've suggested. I completely agree that specifying a password is best.

Comment: I created user, but somehow without the `-h localhost` option, I was never able to login. Kept getting the error `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"`. Does this mean it's trying to connect to some other host? That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @asgs Read the "client authentication" chapter of the manual and read about `pg_hba.conf`. The TL;DR is that you have a different authentication method configured for local connections over unix sockets (`local` mode) than you do over tcp/ip connections (`host` mode) in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 1):

to connect to your database:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname";
    private final String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private final String login = "username";
    private final String password = "";
        private Connection connection = null;
    //...
    try {
    Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                login, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print(" Unable set the connection!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print(" Unable to load the driver class!");
    }
```

Comment: If I do this with port 5433, I get a PSQLException, password authentication failed. if I do it with port 5422 (or by not specifying a port), I get Connection Refused, asking that I check the host name and port.

Comment: By specifying the correct port, this is the proper way to connect, by specifying a blank password, if that's how the user is set up.

Comment: Negative - did not work. If you are relying only on a blank password and have not set up an other mode of password-less authorization then this will not work. So I set a password.