# how to connect JDBC postgres connection without the password when no password is set

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to postgres localhost using JDBC.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=postgres");
```

However the code keeps ask me for password when I have setup passwordless crendential.
For example, I can connect to psql on terminal by typing,

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

And it connects without asking password. How can I connect to postgres without inputing password to the driverManager?

Comment: did you try DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb", "postgres", null) ?

Comment: or DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb", "postgres", "")?

Comment: Yes, and what it says is "The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided."

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369626/connect-as-user-with-no-password-set-on-postgresql-8-4-via-jdbc

Comment: hmm.. doesn't quite solve problem because I have to be able to authenticate without password to support current system. . .

Comment: What happens if you add `-d mydb` to you terminal command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a jdbc connection without specifying a password, but you probably should configure trust authentication for IP sockets. See more info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).